# How to see reference list of a slice/frame of a video using FFprobe

Tags: video, ffmpeg, compression, ffprobe

Suppose I have a avi/mkv/mp4 video, the video has some GOP structure( IPPP/IBBP etc) which can be seen from FFprobe. But can I see reference picture list(L0 and L1), that is frames from which B is using bi-directional prediction using FFprobe?

Answer (score 0):

Since this information is idiosyncratic to each bitstream syntax (codec), it's in the purview of the decoder. So I don't believe ffprobe can access it.

--*Untested approach follows*--

Looking at the source code, it seems you have to define TRACE (let's say, in `libavutil/log.h`), compile and run

```
ffmpeg -loglevel trace -i in.mp4 -f null - 2> log.txt
```

Then the log should contain lines of the format

```
List0: %s fn:%d 0x%p
List1: %s fn:%d 0x%p
```

where the `%d` field will have the picture ID.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it.